# How get the time in milliseconds in FreeBSD?

Tags: shell, freebsd

In Linux I can find the current time in milliseconds using the command:

```
date +%s%N
```

but on FreeBSD I get only

```
[13:38 ]#date +%s%N
1299148740N
```

How can I get the time in milliseconds (or nanoseconds) in FreeBSD?

Comment: `echo $((\`date +%s\`*1000))` for miliseconds or `*1000000000` for nanoseconds.

Comment: I do not want to add zeros, I want to know how many exactly  milliseconds. Maybe, is there a solution on PERL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gettimeofday()`, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int main(void)
{
  struct timeval time_now;
    gettimeofday(&time_now,NULL);
    printf ("%ld secs, %ld usecs\n",time_now.tv_sec,time_now.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was a shell question, not a C question.

Answer (score 6):

The BSD `date` command doesn't support milliseconds.  If you want a `date` with millisecond support, install the GNU `coreutils` package.

I encountered this on OS X, whose `date` comes from BSD.  The solution was to `brew install coreutils` and `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gdate $HOME/bin`, and making sure that `$HOME/bin` comes first in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`tai64n`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64n.html) from [`daemontools`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html):

```
$ echo | tai64n | tai64nlocal
2011-03-03 09:45:37.833010500

$ ps | tai64n | tai64nlocal
2011-03-03 09:52:30.817146500   PID TTY          TIME CMD
2011-03-03 09:52:30.817150500  7154 pts/1    00:00:07 bash
2011-03-03 09:52:30.817157500 20099 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
2011-03-03 09:52:30.817159500 20100 pts/1    00:00:00 tai64n
2011-03-03 09:52:30.817162500 20101 pts/1    00:00:00 tai64nlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for any recent Perl:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=gettimeofday -MPOSIX=strftime -e '($s,$us) = gettimeofday(); printf "%d.%06d\n", $s, $us'
1487594425.611120
```

(modified from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23780) to a similar question)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get milliseconds is to use Python:

```
time_ms=$( python3 -c'import time; print(time.time())' )
echo $time_ms
```

Outputs:

```
1570807434.2774572
```

Note that python 2.x only returns 100ths of a second. May need to be tweaked slightly if your OS is using only Python 2.x to get more granularity.