# How to sleep a random fraction of a second in POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, random, posix, sleep, sh

The following won't work:

```
/bin/sleep $(printf ".%02ds" $(( $RANDOM % 100 )))
```

1. POSIX [sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html#top) supports only integral seconds
2. there is no `$RANDOM`

I could emulate random by:

```
RAND255=$(od -An -N1 -t u1 /dev/urandom)
```

Another option is to write a small C program that utilizes [`usleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) and [`*rand*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/drand48.html) as suggested by [@dmckee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14632/lightweight-utility-program-to-run-a-command-after-a-random-delay/14645#14645) and [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757814/how-to-sleep-a-random-fraction-of-a-second-in-posix-shell/7757923#7757923). Deploying such program might not be always possible.

*Is there a better way* i.e., is there an alternative for sleep in POSIX that accept fractions of a second other than a hand-written C program and is there a better way to emulate `$RANDOM` other than [`od`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html#top)?

Comment: Well, given that reading from `/dev/random` could block for any amount of time, I'm not sure that's going to work out. Or maybe just that read is sufficiently random for your needs :)

Comment: This was tackled on Unix.SE as [Lightweight utility/program to run a command after a random delay](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14632), to which I provided [a programming answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14632/lightweight-utility-program-to-run-a-command-after-a-random-delay/14645#14645).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first command, if `$RANDOM % 100` is 6, for example, it will invoke `/bin/sleep .6s`; you want `/bin/sleep .06s`.

In the second command, `od -An -N1 -t u1 /dev/random` seems to print a number in the range 0..255 -- and the command itself can delay for a long time if `/dev/random` runs out of entropy.  Use `/dev/urandom` instead.

I'd write a small C program that calls `usleep()` (assuming that compiling it and deploying the executable is feasible).

**EDIT**:

As far as I can tell, the answer to your (updated) question is no.

POSIX doesn't guarantee /dev/urandom, so your od command isn't portable to all POSIX systems. I don't believe POSIX specifies any command that can sleep for fractional seconds. It does specify the `nanosleep()` function, but if you can't necessarily deploy a C program that doesn't help. POSIX `awk` has no sleep function.  Perl is not POSIX.

Your options are: (1) sleep only for whole seconds, or (2) use a non-portable method.

What environment(s) do you need this for?

Comment: 0.6 vs. 0.06 doesn't matter in this case. I've replaced `/dev/random` by `/dev/urandom` (It seems that `/dev/urandom` is available everywhere where `/dev/random` is). Deploying C program might be feasible.

Comment: If 0.6 vs. 0.06 doesn't matter, then you're not really sleeping for a random fraction of a second.  Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: @Keith Thompson: The standard says that the argument to `sleep` is an integer. Standard `sleep` cannot sleep for fractions of a second.

Comment: @DarkDust: I know that.  The code in the question uses a version of `sleep` that accepts arguments like `.6s`.

Comment: I've used `printf` to avoid the issue `0.6` vs. `0.06`. The question remains is there an alternative for sleep in POSIX that accept fractions of a second and is there a better way to emulate $RANDOM other than `od`.

Comment: And did my suggestion of writing a small C program not solve your problem?  (It could also call `rand()`, presumably after `srand(time(NULL))`).

Comment: *What environment(s) do you need this for?* For my particular needs: `/bin/sleep $(awk 'BEGIN { srand();  print rand() }')s` works fine. It seems there is no simple way to sleep a fraction of a second using POSIX shell. The last part is out of pure curiosity.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian:  if you call the awk solution above in rapid succession, it will print the same number.  Looks like srand() only changes once per second.

Comment: @arielf: It's `time(NULL)` that only changes once per second.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has `usleep` but on a loaded system, load times probably dominate over short sleeps.

Comment: There is no guarantee that Perl is available.

Answer (score 2):

The Cliff random number generator is a very simple random number generator that “passes the noise sphere test for randomness by showing no structure.” It is easily programmed, in less than 10 lines of awk code:

```
 # cliff_rand.awk --- generate Cliff random numbers



 BEGIN { _cliff_seed = 0.1 }

 function cliff_rand()
 {
     _cliff_seed = (100 * log(_cliff_seed)) % 1
     if (_cliff_seed < 0)
         _cliff_seed = - _cliff_seed
     return _cliff_seed
 }
```

This algorithm requires an initial “seed” of 0.1. Each new value uses the current seed as input for the calculation. If the built-in rand() function (see Numeric Functions) isn't random enough, you might try using this function instead.

Taken from [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Cliff-Random-Function)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for `awk 'BEGIN { srand();  sleep(rand()) }'`. But POSIX `awk` doesn't have `sleep()` function.

Comment: So the random number generation part is fine, right? Only the sleep is a problem?

Comment: Can't you use system() somehow to sleep?... Just a thought off the top of my head/

Comment: `/bin/sleep $(awk 'BEGIN { srand(); print rand() }')s` works fine but [POSIX `sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html) supports only integers for seconds.

Answer (score 2):

this solution works on linux by polling the monotonic counter /proc/uptime - it works even on slow systems for 1/100 of a second exact:

```
#!/bin/sh

WAIT=567        # 5.67 sec

get_up()
{
        read -r UP REST </proc/uptime
        export UP=${UP%.*}${UP#*.}
}

get_up; START=$UP
while :; do get_up; test $((UP-START)) -ge $WAIT && break; done
```

A quick and dirty oneliner (copy/paste!) is here:

```
W=567;x(){ read U R </proc/uptime;U=${U%.*}${U#*.};};x;S=$U;while :;do x;test $((U-S)) -ge $W && break;done
```

Comment: This is neat, but `/proc` is a part of Linux and is not portable to other systems like BSD.

Comment: you are right: so you have to go the e.g. python or perl way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179559/how-get-the-time-in-milliseconds-in-freebsd